# Client data access

Tags: postgresql

First of all, sorry for my english.

I need a 32 bits data access client for an application. There's no more 32 bits version of PG. I have installed odbc in 32 and 64 bits.

When i check the dependencies with Dependency Walker for libpq.dll in odbc directory i can see that just 3 dlls are necessary

- libpq.dll
- libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
- libssl-1_1-x64.dll

If i check the libpq in bin directory of PG server, i have 2 more dependencies:

- libiconv-2.dll
- libintl-8.dll.

So do i really need these 2 dlls or may i use the 3 dlls i've found in odbc directory ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget that the dependencies might themselves have dependencies again. Other than that, the best is to try it out: if the library can be loaded, you got all dependencies.

Comment: Yes i know that and there are no other dependecies. With the dlls in odbc directory, the connection is succesfull, but can i lose some functionality ?

Comment: No. But make sure you are not using an old, outdated version of libpq. By the way, you can always build a 32-bit libpq from source.

Comment: Thank you.I'm going to do extensive tests.